# MongoDB Collections Unexpected Deletion/Drop

Tags: mongodb

Our collections in MongoDB were automatically deleted/drop and we are not sure why and how. Our MongoDB is working fine for almost 10 months now, so we are really not sure what happened here.

Is there a collection expiration for MongoDB where it automatically delete the collections and its data?  Also, would it be possible to retrieve the data?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `db` and `show dbs`?

Answer (score 4):

Collections do not 'drop' themselves.
Someone has run `db.collection.drop()` somewhere, intentionally, or accidentally.

You can set a TTL on the data inside a collection - [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) however I don't think that's what has happened here.

The only way of retrieving the data would be from a backup.

Restoring a backup to a secondary database and taking a copy of the collection in question, then importing that back into your main database may be the best approach here.
... You do have backups, right?